# ESLint not notifying about certain errors?

Tags: json, reactjs, visual-studio-code, gatsby, eslint

I'm trying to set up a React app with Gatsby, and for some reason the ESLint doesn't seem to be fully working properly.

I put the code `const test = 4;` and left the variable unused, which I would expect to throw an unused-variable error in ESLint, but it does not.

I use VSCode.

This is my eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

These are the dependencies in my `package.json`

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "gatsby": "^2.24.67",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.12.102",
    "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^2.1.10",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
```

Comment: @AllanChain the error does show up in terminal when doing `npm run start`, but doesn't show up on VSCode under the "Problems" tab

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the rule in your `eslintrc.json` file:

```
"rules":{
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
}
```

Of course, you can change the warning for your desired behavior. You can check for further details in [ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/rules/no-unused-vars).